# how to optimizing boolean function?

Tags: optimization, theory, set

im facing the challange of optimizing a database design by an automated mechanism.
the database will include tables which relates arbitrary data to an attribute
e.g. Table A contains all id's of persons who clicked the buy button, Table B contains all id's who have no chargeback, ....

so given are some very basic MainTables e.g. A,B,C,D which shall be composed by set theory (union, intersect, complement) operations using some kind of GUI, resulting in new SubsetTables

as more subset's are created, they more and more depend on each other, e.g. E=(A and B), F=(A and B and C) - both are boolean function, and id of a person is within those set's or not

now i try to optimize the database query which fills/queries my table's so that the query is not F=(A join B join C) but F=(E join C), which makes sense cause E contains fewer rows as its already a subset

finally this means im asking which, if any, mathematical/software algorithm can optimize my problem with many set's and subset's (maybe a few hundred) so i can query and fill the tables efficiently

i already thought about creating new subset's only using the information of MainSet's and optimizing those GUI-created-Subset using Karnaugh-Veitch-Algorithm, but this would lead in e.g. A and B and C. I dont know how to take the second step of optimization to transform (A and B and C) to (E and C) and with even more complexity resulting in the problem of finding most efficient combination of (sub)set's

thx for any advice

Comment: im not yet sure, but to have an answer, i think the solution lies within the question. I think its also possible to use KV for such optimaziations. The point is to include all Subsets in the process too. Not only the MainSet's e.g. doing KV over A,B,C,E for (A and B And C) will result in (E and C) cause it would be the smalles term - but im not sure if its right what i said

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be that there is some other reason why you are unable to change your table schema, however if you are able to change the schema I recommend that you instead have a single table containing the IDs of all people, and have boolean (bit) columns for each of your data, so for example:

```
ID  A  B  C
--- -- -- --
1   1  0  1
2   1  1  0
etc...
```

This means that the database server will do all of the optimisation for you:

```
-- Select all people in set A
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE A = 1

-- Select all people in set E
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE A = 1 AND B = 1

-- Select all people in set F
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE A = 1 AND B = 1 AND C = 1
```

(I'd also recommend giving your columns better names)